# NameServers Changed:How to check the domain name hitting my server?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, domain, ip, nameserver

How do I check the domain name that has been used to access my server using PHP?

I have several domains that I have changed the name servers for and now I want to be able to check the domain that is hitting my server?

Would be grateful for links to read up on this sort of thing and how to test.

Thanks all

Comment: DNS servers do not "hit" servers. An "nslookup" can be used to query a DNS server.

Answer (score 2):

I have done something like the following (which redirected depending upon the requesting URL but you can do whatever you need to do)

```
<?php
     $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

     header("Content-type: text/html");
     // depending upon which 'Host' was in the URL,
     // we redirect to different places or nowhere at all
     if ( $url == 'www.example.org.uk'
                || $url == 'www.example.me.uk' ) {
             header("Location: http://www.example.co.uk/");
     }
     else if ( $url == 'www.example.net'
            || $url == 'www.example.org' ) {
             header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
     }
     // otherwise default
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can tell which name server was used by the client if that is what you are asking.  You can only see what the domain was that they requested because it is in the HTTP header.  Doing this with PHP should probably be on stackoverflow.

If you are running Apache as your webserver, you can just look at the access_log file, which would be in something like /var/log/httpd/access_log to see which domain they are requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am not understanding the question correctly, you can easily check for what domain is hitting your server using:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

Does seem more appropriate for Stack Overflow though...